# Putting balls into bins while satisfying constraints

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics, brute-force

My problem can be reduced to the following:

I have `11` integersc(balls) (numbered from 1 to 11) and `4` boxes (bins) (boxes `A, B, C, D`). I want to count the number of distributions of the `11` integers into the `4` boxes that satisfy the following constraints:

- The box `A` has a capacity of 1 (only 1 integer fits into it at one time)
- Boxes `B, C, D` cannot contain 2 integers which sum up to 13
- An integer can only be placed into a box it likes.

What I have is a list of those `11` integers and the boxes they like (indicated as `x->A,B,C,D` which can be read as "integer x likes boxes A,B,C,D"):

`1->(A, D)`, `2->(B)`, `3->(B)`, `4->(B)`, `5->(B)`, `6->(C)`, `7->(C,D)` , `8->(C,D)`, `9->(C,D)`, `10->(C,D)`, `11->(D)`.

In this case the solution is 8, there are 8 possible ways to dristribute the integers among the boxes:

A=[1], B=[2,3,4,5], C=[6,8,9,10], D=[7,11] and 7 more distributions where 8,9,10 are distributed differently among boxes C and D.

Now doing this on paper is fine but I'm struggling with finding a systematic way (brute force) to go through all the possible distributions which satisfy the constraints. My approach consists of 11 for loops (one for each number), each of the loops iterates through a list (each number has a list filled with boxes it likes). I got lost in trying to enforce the constraints while counting the number of distributions, is there a more elegant, a more general way of solving this balls into bins while satisfying some constraints problem?

Comment: Your current approach sounds good. Can you add the code (or pseudo-code) to your post?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Define Box classes.

```
abstract class Box {

    Set<Integer> balls = new HashSet<>();
    abstract boolean canAdd(int n);

    boolean add(int n) {
        if (!canAdd(n)) return false;
        balls.add(n);
        return true;
    }

    void remove(int n) { balls.remove(n); }
    @Override public String toString() { return balls.toString(); }
}

class Box1 extends Box {
    // has a capacity of 1 (only 1 integer fits into it at one time)
    boolean canAdd(int n) {
        return balls.size() < 1;
    }
}

class Box13 extends Box {
    // cannot contain 2 integers which sum up to 13
    boolean canAdd(int n) {
        int remain = 13 - n;
        return !balls.contains(remain);
    }
}
```

(2) Define actual boxes.

```
Box A = new Box1();
Box B = new Box13();
Box C = new Box13();
Box D = new Box13();
```

(3) Define integer's preferences.

```
Box[][] likes =  {
    /*  0 */ {},
    /*  1 */ {A, D},
    /*  2 */ {B},
    /*  3 */ {B},
    /*  4 */ {B},
    /*  5 */ {B},
    /*  6 */ {C},
    /*  7 */ {C, D},
    /*  8 */ {C, D},
    /*  9 */ {C, D},
    /* 10 */ {C, D},
    /* 11 */ {D},
};
```

(5) Find solutions.

```
for (Box b1 : likes[1]) {
    if (!b1.add(1)) continue;
    for (Box b2 : likes[2]) {
        if (!b2.add(2)) continue;
        for (Box b3 : likes[3]) {
            if (!b3.add(3)) continue;
            for (Box b4 : likes[4]) {
                if (!b4.add(4)) continue;
                for (Box b5 : likes[5]) {
                    if (!b5.add(5)) continue;
                    for (Box b6 : likes[6]) {
                        if (!b6.add(6)) continue;
                        for (Box b7 : likes[7]) {
                            if (!b7.add(7)) continue;
                            for (Box b8 : likes[8]) {
                                if (!b8.add(8)) continue;
                                for (Box b9 : likes[9]) {
                                    if (!b9.add(9)) continue;
                                    for (Box b10 : likes[10]) {
                                        if (!b10.add(10)) continue;
                                        for (Box b11 : likes[11]) {
                                            if (!b11.add(11)) continue;
                                            System.out.printf("A=%s B=%s C=%s D=%s%n",
                                                A, B, C, D);
                                            b11.remove(11);
                                        }
                                        b10.remove(10);
                                    }
                                    b9.remove(9);
                                }
                                b8.remove(8);
                            }
                            b7.remove(7);
                        }
                        b6.remove(6);
                    }
                    b5.remove(5);
                }
                b4.remove(4);
            }
            b3.remove(3);
        }
        b2.remove(2);
    }
    b1.remove(1);
}
```

RESULT

```
A=[1] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 8, 9, 10] D=[7, 11]
A=[1] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 8, 9] D=[7, 10, 11]
A=[1] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 8, 10] D=[7, 9, 11]
A=[1] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 8] D=[7, 9, 10, 11]
A=[1] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 9, 10] D=[7, 8, 11]
A=[1] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 9] D=[7, 8, 10, 11]
A=[1] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 10] D=[7, 8, 9, 11]
A=[1] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6] D=[7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
A=[] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 8, 9, 10] D=[1, 7, 11]
A=[] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 8, 9] D=[1, 7, 10, 11]
A=[] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 8, 10] D=[1, 7, 9, 11]
A=[] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 8] D=[1, 7, 9, 10, 11]
A=[] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 9, 10] D=[1, 7, 8, 11]
A=[] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 9] D=[1, 7, 8, 10, 11]
A=[] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6, 10] D=[1, 7, 8, 9, 11]
A=[] B=[2, 3, 4, 5] C=[6] D=[1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Recursive solver is

```
static void solve(Box A, Box B, Box C, Box D, Box[][] likes, int n) {
    if (n > 11) {
        System.out.printf("A=%s B=%s C=%s D=%s%n", A, B, C, D);
        return;
    }
    for (Box box : likes[n]) {
        if (!box.add(n)) continue;
        solve(A, B, C, D, likes, n + 1);
        box.remove(n);
    }
}
```

And

```
solve(A, B, C, D, likes, 1);
```

Comment: I like how you enforced the constraints, such a general approach allows for lot's of reuse, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounds fine.

Choose a way to represent the distribution of balls into boxes (e.g. an array, with the ball as the index and the box as the value).

Write a function `isDistributionValid(distribution)` that takes a distribution and returns `true` if all the constraints are satisfied. You might want to write following helper functions:

- `getBallsInBox(distribution, box)`: returns a list with all the balls that are assigned to `box` in the distribution
- `count(distribution, box)`: returns the number of balls that are assigned to `box` in the distribution
- `anyPairSumsToTarget(list, target)`: returns `true` if any pair of values in `list` sums to `target` (hint: use two nested for-loops)

Inside the innermost of the 11 loops, call `isDistributionValid` with the representation of the current distribution. If the result is true, increment a counter.

---

#### Recursive Solution

There is a more elegant way using recursion. It has less repetitive code and the number of balls does not have to be fixed. The idea is to write a function

```
count_distributions(current_ball, last_ball, distribution)
```

When the function is called, all the balls before `current_ball` should have already been assigned to boxes and the assignment should be stored in `distribution`. The function returns the number of valid distributions that can be produced by assigning the remaining balls to boxes. To do that, the function iterates over the possible boxes for `current_ball`, and for each possibility it recursively calls `count_distributions(current_ball+1, last_ball, new_distribution)` and sums the results. As a base case, if `current_ball` is greater than `last_ball`, the distribution is complete and the function should check if the distribution is valid and return 1 if it is or 0 if it isn't. The function is started off using `count_distributions(1, 11, empty_distribution)`.

Pseudocode:

```
function count_distributions(current_ball, last_ball, distribution):
    if current_ball > last_ball:
        // all the balls have been distributed
        if distribution is valid:
            return 1
        else
            return 0
    sum = 0
    // try each possibility for current_ball
    for chosen_box in boxes that current_ball likes:
        new_distribution = copy(distribution)
        update new_distribution so current_ball maps to chosen_box
        // recursively try remaining balls
        sum += count_distributions(current_ball + 1, last_ball, new_distribution)
    return sum

print(count_distributions(1, 11, empty distribution))
```

#### Optimizations

It is possible to make both versions significantly faster by terminating early if the current incomplete distribution is invalid. Every time a (ball, box) assignment is added to the distribution, check that the incomplete distribution is valid. If it isn't, there is no point in continuing with that distribution.

The constraints can be checked more efficiently by adding more information to the representation of the distribution, but I won't go into the details.